# What is the purpose of the [manage] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [manage](/questions/tagged/manage) tag seems useless, and there is little in common of any use between the questions.

Comment: There aren't showing any questions up for me...?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Must be you, I see 49 questions with that tag.

Comment: @RobW: Arrrrr...yeah...ignored tags and such...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has been deleted.